# Create a User Area

Tags: joomla-3.x, user, login, mvc, best-practices

I'm wondering how i can create a User Area for users to login and gain access to a user panel  (where user can update their info and specfic/custom actions). Because the Joomla user login functionality actually doesn't do much (as far as i know, if someone can make more clarifications on how this works...).

I mean i don't think Joomla can provide what i need so i have to create a new MVC for that, right?

**So my question is:**

1. The correct way to do it should be creating/extending a component using MVC (with login view, panel view, etc)?
2. If so, can i take advantage of the Joomla user login system using the same username and password previously set by the user or i should create a new table for users to signup/login?

Or is there any other way to get it done? And what are the best practices for it.

So in short, what i want is: a user logs in then has access to an exclusive and customizable user area. Is this possible by, somewhow, extending the core's Joomla login/registration system or i have to create a new MVC (in a custom component) for that? If so, should i create a new table or use Joomla's users table?

Comment: "all that kind of things" ...please define exactly what you are trying to do.  The less vague you are, the easier it is for volunteers to help you.  Should you create a separate user table from the core's table? I'd say in 99.999% of cases that it is wasteful to scrap the core's user login/registration system.

Comment: Yes i mean, let's say i want to create a custom user area for user to perform actions (certain actions); i will probably have to create a new MVC for that, right? If so, should i create a new table for user to register and login to this user area or i can use the core's user login/registration system as you said?  Because i will probably have to create a new MVC anyway for the user area because i want the users to perform custom actions. Might be a simple question but i really don't know what to do especially when it comes about the login/registration. Should i create a new table or not?

Answer (score 2):

Two questions:

- Do you want your users log in front or backend of your site?
  The workflow is a little different for each scenario.
- What user functionality you want?, or want to extend?, once the user has logged in.

---

To provide this to your users you need already establish your [user groups](https://docs.joomla.org/Help39:Users_Groups).

The first case: if you want to provide a **"user menu"** in the front-end:

1. Create a new menu in **Menus** > **Manage** > **Add new Menu**
   Here you need to select if the menu is for front or backend.
2. Create the menu items for the user menu.
   Here you can see the available options:

[image: Menu items available for user menu]

3. Now, you need to establish the access level, assign each menu item to your user group.
4. Assign you user menu to one menu module.
   Create a new menu module in **Extensions** > **Modules** > **New** > **Menu**, inside select the user menu, select the position in your template and select the access level for your user group.
5. Extend the user profile.
   Go to **Extensions** > **Plugins** > **User - Profile**, From here you can find more options available, let's say that I need a Zip Code or Country info from my users, well, here you have this options, let's say that I need to know their favorite star wars movie, well, you also can [override the text string](https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Language_Overrides_in_Joomla) to the info you want.

Hope this helps as a starting point.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, that helps too, but i want something more "advanced". I actually i wanted a custom user area (like user panel where they can perform certain actions). How can i achieve this? By creating a new MVC? If so, should i create a new table for users or use Joomla user table?

Comment: Yes exactly. I want the user to perfom certain actions. Is there any possibility to extend the core's login/user panel system or should i create a new MVC for that? What's the best option. And should i create a new table for that or not? According to @mickmackusa, this is not a good idea. Because i actually don't know about the Jooml'as login stystem but as far as i know it doesn't provide much.

Comment: Hi @Thiago, please explain us what you mean with "perform certain actions".

Comment: It's  a user's panel like Joomla's administrator panel but for users. The users log in and then they are redirected  to a user panel where they can perform actions related to my site. What's the best way of achieving this?

Comment: Ok, Maybe the best option here is create your own [MVC component](https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Developing_an_MVC_Component), in this way you can add [Backend actions](https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Developing_an_MVC_Component/Adding_backend_actions) and extend it with the standard [Form fields](https://docs.joomla.org/Form_field). Follow the [Secure Coding Guidelines](https://docs.joomla.org/Secure_coding_guidelines) and the [Development Best Practices](https://docs.joomla.org/Development_Best_Practices).

Comment: Yeah that's what i thought. I just wanted someone with more experience to confirm it, Thank you.

Comment: One more question, should i create a new table for users or use Joomla users table?

Comment: Since it's a new extension, I would go the way of creating a new one.